# VBScript - Retrieving a user's nested groups and getting rid of repetitions

Tags: windows, recursion, vbscript, active-directory, nested-groups

For my work, I have to write a script in VBScript that retrieves a list of ALL groups a user belongs to, including nested groups, and take out nested groups that would be repeated throughout the list (as well as indent nested groups, further indent nested groups of nested groups, etc.)

I found a script that fetches the entire list of groups a user belongs to by Monimoy Sanyal on gallery.technet.microsoft.com, and tried to adapt it to my needs. Here is the script as edited by me:

```
Option Explicit

Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppend = 8

Dim ObjUser, ObjRootDSE, ObjConn, ObjRS
Dim GroupCollection, ObjGroup
Dim StrUserName, StrDomName, StrSQL
Dim GroupsList
Dim WriteFile

GroupsList = ""

Set ObjRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
StrDomName = Trim(ObjRootDSE.Get("DefaultNamingContext"))
Set ObjRootDSE = Nothing

StrUserName = InputBox("Enter user login", "Info needed", "")
StrSQL = "Select ADsPath From 'LDAP://" & StrDomName & "' Where ObjectCategory = 'User' AND SAMAccountName = '" & StrUserName & "'"

Set ObjConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
ObjConn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject":  ObjConn.Open "Active Directory Provider"
Set ObjRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
ObjRS.Open StrSQL, ObjConn
If Not ObjRS.EOF Then
    ObjRS.MoveLast: ObjRS.MoveFirst
    Set ObjUser = GetObject (Trim(ObjRS.Fields("ADsPath").Value))
    Set GroupCollection = ObjUser.Groups
    WScript.Echo "Looking for groups " & StrUserName & " is member of. This may take some time..."
    'Groups with direct membership, and calling recursive function for nested groups
    For Each ObjGroup In GroupCollection
        GroupsList = GroupsList + ObjGroup.CN + VbCrLf
        CheckForNestedGroup ObjGroup
    Next
    Set ObjGroup = Nothing: Set GroupCollection = Nothing:  Set ObjUser = Nothing
    'Writing list in a file named Groups <username>.txt
    Set WriteFile = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Dim fso, f
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("Groups " & StrUserName & ".txt", ForWriting,true)
        f.write(GroupsList)
        f.Close
        WScript.Echo "You can find the list in the Groups " &StrUserName & ".txt file that has just been created."
Else
    WScript.Echo "Couldn't find user " & StrUserName & " in AD."
End If
ObjRS.Close:    Set ObjRS = Nothing
ObjConn.Close:  Set ObjConn = Nothing

'Recursive fucntion
Private Sub CheckForNestedGroup(ObjThisGroupNestingCheck)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim AllMembersCollection, StrMember, StrADsPath, ObjThisIsNestedGroup
    AllMembersCollection = ObjThisGroupNestingCheck.GetEx("MemberOf")
    For Each StrMember in AllMembersCollection
        StrADsPath = "LDAP://" & StrMember
        Set ObjThisIsNestedGroup = GetObject(StrADsPath)
        'Not include a group in the list if it is already in the list (does not work for some reason?)
        If InStr(GroupsList, ObjThisIsNestedGroup.CN) = 0 Then
            GroupsList = GroupsList + vbTab + ObjThisIsNestedGroup.CN + VbCrLf
        End If
        'Recursion to look for nested groups and nested groups of nested groups and nested groups of nested groups of nested groups and...
        CheckForNestedGroup ObjThisIsNestedGroup
    Next
    Set ObjThisIsNestedGroup = Nothing: Set StrMember = Nothing:    Set AllMembersCollection = Nothing
End Sub
```

Rather than display a popup for EACH group found like the original script did, I store the entire list in a String (`GroupsList = GroupsList + ObjGroup.CN + VbCrLf` for direct groups, `GroupsList = GroupsList + vbTab + ObjThisIsNestedGroup.CN + VbCrLf` for nested groups in the recursive function,) and once the script is done looking for groups, it saves the String in a file. (`f.write(GroupsList)`)

My problem is, despite the `If "InStr(GroupsList, ObjThisIsNestedGroup.CN) = 0` in the recursive function, I still find myself with tons of repetitions throughout the results (our AD is kind of bloated with groups, it is a huge structure with many nested groups and nested groups in other nested groups, etc.) and the check doesn't seem to notice that ObjThisIsNestedGroup.CN is already found in GroupsList.
And I have no idea how to implement the indentation properly.

Any ideas? I'm rather new at scripting, so forgive me if the answer is obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for both problems. Well, the first problem I'm not sure how I fixed since I only reverted the code after making a modification and then it was magically working. 
For the increasing indentation, I declared a global variable named RecurCount that I increment every time I call the recursive procedure, and decrease after the procedure. Then, within the procedure, I added a For i = 0 to RecurCount that adds a varying number of vbTabs depending on RecurCount.

Here's the working procedure:

```
Private Sub CheckForNestedGroup(ObjThisGroupNestingCheck)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim AllMembersCollection, StrMember, StrADsPath, ObjThisIsNestedGroup, TabAdd, i 
    AllMembersCollection = ObjThisGroupNestingCheck.GetEx("MemberOf")
    For Each StrMember in AllMembersCollection
        If StrMember <> "" Then
            StrADsPath = "LDAP://" & StrMember
            Set ObjThisIsNestedGroup = GetObject(StrADsPath)
            'If InStr(GroupsList, ObjThisIsNestedGroup.CN) = 0 Then (Uncomment this If and indent lines below to remove groups already in the list)
            TabAdd = ""
            For i = 0 to Recurcount
                TabAdd = TabAdd & vbTab
            Next
            GroupsList = GroupsList & TabAdd & " " & ObjThisIsNestedGroup.CN & VbCrLf
            'End If
            'Recursion to include nested groups of nested groups
            Recurcount = Recurcount + 1
            CheckForNestedGroup ObjThisIsNestedGroup
            Recurcount = Recurcount - 1
        End If
    Next
    Set ObjThisIsNestedGroup = Nothing: Set StrMember = Nothing:    Set AllMembersCollection = Nothing
End Sub
```

Don't forget to Dim Recurcount in the main script, and to make it 0 right before calling CheckForNestedGroup for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Add the groups as keys to a [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), so the list contains only unique names, and [`Join()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yscc53h0%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) the `Keys` array for output:

```
Set GroupsList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
GroupsList.CompareMode = vbTextCompare  'make keys case-insensitive
...
GroupsList(ObjGroup.CN) = True
...
f.Write Join(GroupsList.Keys, vbNewLine)
```

Comment: Hey, 
I added the first two lines after the Dims, the middle line instead of GroupsList = GroupsList + ObjGroup.CN + VbCrLf (and the same with the recursive), and the f.write instead of the previous one. 
Now it gives me an error undefined variable 'ObjGroup.CN' 800A01F4 at line 34 (the middle line in your response.) 
I'm not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: @RinNagamine Sorry, my mistake. You need parentheses instead of square brackets in that line.

Comment: Ah, I see. I did the change, and I ran it with the parentheses, but now it only returns me with the direct membership groups, not a single nested group.

Comment: ... I reverted back to my old code, not a single change, just uncommented the lines and commented yours, and now the duplicates /are/ removed from the results. I don't get it. Though I still can't get the indentation right for nested groups of nested groups etc...